# Perl script multi thread not running parallel

Tags: mysql, multithreading, perl

I am completely new to Perl, like absolute newbie. I am trying to develop a system which reads a database and, according to the results, generates a queue which launches another script.

[HERE](http://www.mindzone.co.th/multi_thread.pl.txt) is the source code.

Now the script works as expected, except I have noticed that it doesn't really do the threads parallel. Whether I use 1 thread or 50 threads, the execution time is the same; 1 thread is even faster.
When I have the script display which thread did what, I see the threads don't run at the same time, because it will do thread 1, then 2, then 3 etc.

Does anyone know what I did wrong here? Again the script itself works, just not in parallel threads.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to learn what semaphores actually are before you start using them. You've explicitly told the threads *not* to run in parallel:

```
my $s           = Thread::Semaphore->new;
#...

    while ($queue_id_list->pending > 0) { 
        $s->down;
        my $info = $queue_id_list->dequeue_nb;
        if (defined($info)) {
            my @details = split(/#/, $info);
            #my $result = system("./match_name db=user_".$details[0]." id=".$details[1]); 
            # normally the script above would be launched which is a php script run in php-cli and does some database things

            sleep(0.1);

            #print "Thread: ". threads->self->tid. " - Done user: ".$details[0]. " and addressbook id: ". $details[1]."\r\n";
            #print $queue_id_list->pending."\r\n";
        }
        $s->up;
    }
```

You've created a semaphore `$s`, which by default has a count of 1. Then in the function you're trying to run, you call `$s->down` at the start -- which decreases the count by 1, or blocks if the count is already <1, and `$s->up` at the end, which increases the count by 1.

Once a thread calls `down`, no other threads will run until it calls `up` again.

You should carefully read [the Thread::Semaphore docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/Thread/Semaphore.html), and probably [this wikipedia article on semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), too.

Comment: So what you are saying (correct me if I am wrong) if I remove the semaphore it would work? Like I said...newbie on perl

Comment: @renevdkool: Assuming you don't do anything that needs to be serialized. Why did you put the semaphore there in the first place?

Comment: actually I have no idea. I used a sample threading script and edited it to my situation. The idea came from a webcrawler script. I just thought I needed it.

Comment: @renevdkool: Semaphores are common in threaded applications, but they have a specific purpose -- they're supposed to be used to prevent too many threads from using the same resource. Unless you know there's a limit on how many threads you can have simultaneously executing that block of code, the semaphore is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: taking the semaphore away took it down to 4 minutes with 25 threads. thank you very much for your time and answer...if you have any remarks on my code to improve it it would be appreciated.

Comment: I have removed the semaphore statements. The script is now about 2 minutes faster. BUT... it doesn't matter how many  threads I initialize, it's the same time. 1 thread, 10 threads, 25 threads.

Comment: How many processor/cores does the machine you're running this on have? What would you expect to happen with 25 threads with, say, 1 processor/core? Each additional thread above the first would just take processor time away from the first, no?

Comment: The machine has 1CPU/2Cores. I always thought a core can handle 1 process, but 1 process could use more threads. So there is no way to speed this up? Except for adding more CPU's? Would the script as it is, use the multiple cpus or would it only work with 1?

Comment: @renevdkool: CPU scheduling is per "thread of execution", not process. Think of a process as a container of 1 or more threads. Also, each of your threads is launching an external script -- that starts a whole separate process for each thread. More processes or threads than CPU cores can be useful if they're waiting on I/O (e.g. network traffic or disk read/writes), but on any given cycle, 1 CPU core can execute exactly 1 thread, period.